# Song from the 60s-80s-ish?

Tags: identify-this-song, rock

My school faculty members put on a band that played oldies and one of them was really catchy and I wanted to find it. It has the lyrics "my my my my" and "I'm movin' on" occasionally! Please help! Google searches didn't help.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it's exactly ***I'm movin on*** multiple times?

If not I think you mean **Catch Me Daddy, by either Janis Joplin solo (1982) or originally Big Brother and The holding Company (1968).** That song was one of the two that latter band, were Joplin was the lead singer of, was best known for.

To be precise both lines only ones used:

> You know, I want ya, need ya, I gotta have ya 'Cause I want ya need
>   ya, 'cause I gotta have ya 'Cause this my-my-my-my-my-my-my-man
>   My-my-my-my-my-my-my-man now

And the other:

> Cold sheets made me realize, catch me, daddy, '**cause I'm movin' on**
>
> Come on up, come on up, come up, I've **got to move on**
>
> Oh, I guess I might finally walk in there I gotta, gotta, gotta,
>   **gotta move on**

...

Note: I also used Google Search, specifically

intext:lyrics "my my my my" "movin on"
As you can see in some form Stevie Wonder and Led Zeppelin were among candidates, just not both lines ^^